# On key up Ajax function for checking if name exist returns multiple identical values despite using codeigniter active record distinct query

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

I have utilized on key up function with ajax to check in my database if the course name already exist. A prompt then will be showed to the user after a match is found. I have used the distinct query in my model  and then the controller returns the right value to the ajax however the returned value were duplicated or even multiple values are returned causing the pop up message in my page to show multiple times also. What is wrong with this? Thanks for the help.Here are my codes

View (Javascript):

```
<script>
var typingTimer;
var doneTypingInterval = 3000;


$('#course_name').keyup(function(){
typingTimer = setTimeout(check_course_name_exist, doneTypingInterval);

});


$('#course_name').keydown(function(){
clearTimeout(typingTimer);

});



function check_course_name_exist()
   {

   var course_name=$("#course_name").val();

    var postData={
    'course_name':course_name
   };


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>courses/check_course_name_existince",
        dataType:'json',
        data: postData,
        success: function(data)
        {


        if(data.msg == 'Exist')
        {
         console.log(data.msg);
         $("#alert_exist").fadeIn(100);
         $("#alert_exist").delay(3000).fadeOut(1000);
         var a = 0;
         $("input[type=radio][value=" + a + "]").attr("disabled",true);
         document.getElementById('course_desc').disabled=true;
         document.getElementById('userfile').disabled=true;
         document.getElementById('is_public').disabled=true;
         document.getElementById('submit').disabled=true;


        }

        else
         {
         console.log(data.msg);
         var a = 0;
         $("input[type=radio][value=" + a + "]").attr("disabled",false);
         document.getElementById('course_desc').disabled=false;
         document.getElementById('userfile').disabled=false;
         document.getElementById('is_public').disabled=false;
         document.getElementById('submit').disabled=false;


         }



        }
    });
   </script>
```

Controller:

```
function check_course_name_existince()
{
$course_name = $this->input->post('course_name');
$session_id = $this->session->userdata('username');
$result = $this->
course_booking_model->check_course_name_exist($session_id,$course_name);

if($result)
    {


        $msg="Exist";
    }
    else
    {

        $msg="Available";
    }


echo json_encode(array('msg'=>$msg));
}
```

Model:

```
function check_course_name_exist($tennant_id,$course_name)
{
  $where = array(

        'tennant_id'  => $tennant_id,
        'course_name' => $course_name

  );
    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->select('course_name');
    $this->db->where($where);
    $this->db->group_by('course_name');
    $query=$this->db->get("courses");


  if($query->num_rows()>0)
    {
       return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Image Output:

[image]

The console log function returns 2 identical values resulting to 2 message pop up.

Comment: if you type really fast I think `check_course_name_exist` will be called multiple times

Comment: Its because of your `keyup` function which is called multiple times when the user starts typing.

Comment: Does it still call my controller method in every type of a character? even if the doneTypingInterval = 3000; is set to 3 seconds?

Comment: If it calls my controller method in every type of a character, it shouldn't still return the exist value because I did not use the like query.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with your query since you're only checking the number of rows, that means it doesn't matter how many rows your query returns the output will be the same as long it is more than one

Comment: I also observed that when two identical course name exist in my table, and type that course name in the input field, that when it returns multiple values but if there is only one record for a certain course in the database then I typed the same course name, it works fine even I have typed it very fast.

Comment: but there's no part of your code that is affected by the number of rows in your query result, you could query your whole table and it would only display one message, the problem is in the number of ajax calls that you're making, place an alert inside your `check_course_name_exist()` function in Javascript to see when the ajax calls are being triggered

Comment: Yeah you're right koala_dev. I have been changing my code back and forth. Even with  in my model return $this->db->count_all_results(); and result > 0 in controller, still the same output. What should be the right adjustment for this?

Comment: I placed alert function in check_course_name_exist now. The alert displayed after 3 seconds, but why there are instances that after 3 seconds, multiple alert was called?

Comment: If I typed a course name with a single match in the database, the alert function showed just once but if I typed a course name with 2 records of the same course name stored in the database, multiple alert showed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding some checks before setting a new timeout to prevent multiple triggers to your ajax call

```
var typingTimer = null;
var doneTypingInterval = 3000;

$('#course_name').keyup(function () {
    if (!typingTimer) {
        typingTimer = setTimeout(check_course_name_exist, doneTypingInterval);
    }

});

$('#course_name').keydown(function () {
    if (typingTimer) {
        clearTimeout(typingTimer);
        typingTimer = null;
    }
});
```